# Bootstrap width displays incorreclty with Owl carousel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I have an issue with width of my bootstrap columns. Without Owl carousel everything works ok, but i don't know why it doesn't work with this plugin. 
These are just 5 similar blocks of code. Every block starts with .col-md-3 class. 
The result of this code:

[image]

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".team-members").owlCarousel({
   autoPlay: 3000,
   items : 4,
   itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
   itemsDesktopSmall : [973,3]
  });
    });
```

```html
 <section id="team">
  <div class="container">
   <h4>Our team</h4>
   <div class="owl-carousel team-members">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
     <div class="member">
      <div class="member-img">
       <img src="img/man.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="member-info">
       <span>Jerry Mack</span>
       <i>Web-developer</i>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis</p>
      </div>
      <div class="member-contacts">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
       <i id="middle-icon" class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
       <i id="last-icon" class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
     <div class="member">
      <div class="member-img">
       <img src="img/man.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="member-info">
       <span>Jerry Mack</span>
       <i>Web-developer</i>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis</p>
      </div>
      <div class="member-contacts">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
       <i id="middle-icon" class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
       <i id="last-icon" class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
     <div class="member">
      <div class="member-img">
       <img src="img/man.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="member-info">
       <span>Jerry Mack</span>
       <i>Web-developer</i>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis</p>
      </div>
      <div class="member-contacts">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
       <i id="middle-icon" class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
       <i id="last-icon" class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
     <div class="member">
      <div class="member-img">
       <img src="img/man.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="member-info">
       <span>Jerry Mack</span>
       <i>Web-developer</i>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis</p>
      </div>
      <div class="member-contacts">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
       <i id="middle-icon" class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
       <i id="last-icon" class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
     <div class="member">
      <div class="member-img">
       <img src="img/man.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="member-info">
       <span>Jerry Mack</span>
       <i>Web-developer</i>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis</p>
      </div>
      <div class="member-contacts">
       <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
       <i id="middle-icon" class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
       <i id="last-icon" class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

The result of this code:
[The result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXGMC.png)

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer. Owl carousel wraps every element in .owl-item class, so .col-md-3 means 25% of .owl-item class. All you need is write this class in the div with .col-md-3.
It should be something like this:

```html
<div class="owl-item col-md-3 col-sm-3">
 <div class="member">
  <div class="member-img">
   <img src="img/man.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="member-info">
   <span>Jerry Mack</span>
   <i>Web-developer</i>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis</p>
  </div>
  <div class="member-contacts">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
   <i id="middle-icon" class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
   <i id="last-icon" class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```